# How to determine free memory within a program running on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

I've got a software running on Linux that is leaking memory.  It's an embedded system so I don't have a lot of debugging tools so I'm using printf's.

Short of doing something like 'popen()'ing a call to 'cat /proc/meminfo' and scanning for the MemFree line, is there a way I can put this information in a printf?

At present I'm doing something akin to:

```
# ./myprogram &
# for (( c=0; c<99; c++)) do echo --- $c --- && cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree: && sleep 30; done;
```

Which is okay, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

---

Edit: The four responses so far aren't quite what I was looking for, I wasn't specific enough.

It appears my program isn't the cause of the memory leak; regardless I was looking to see if I could add some 'c' code that would see/report the free memory in the system, not how much memory my code (process) is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to see free system memory?
On most unix platforms, that value will always tend toward zero.
The reason:
 - filesystem blocks are cached, in case someone needs them again
 - blocks are only released if some process needs memory
 - these blocks are favored because the backing store is the filesystem,
   so stealing those blocks is cheap ... no page-out required.

Answer (score 2):

Two library calls that may be of use:

- `getrusage` will let you obtain the current program (and optionally, child processes) Resident Set Size;
- `sbrk(0)` will return the current position of the program break, which will increase as the program heap size is increased.

Comment: Useful tools in their own right; but niether address what I'm looking for, a c callable routine which can report the size of the physical memory free.

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` command is useful, try e.g.

```
watch -n 1 ps v `pgrep ./myprogram`
```

but you could of course also try to tell `top`, `htop` and their graphical variants to just watch your process.

Else you can try the same by querying for your own process id, the look up /proc/$PID and read the memory info from there so that your `printf` can report them while running.

Comment: 'm looking for a c callable routine which can report the size of the physical memory free.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mallinfo (though it's somewhat obsolete... I've used it once with success)
http://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/finding-memory-leaks-with-mallinfo/

Also, njamd (or electric fence, or any other LD_PRELOAD based malloc debuggers might help):
http://sourceforge.net/projects/njamd/

also, mtrace may be of interest:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace